# Stainless steel vs ceramic Enamel microwave ovens

Tags: microwave

I want to buy a convection microwave oven. I plan to buy either from LG or from samsung .Almost all LG products have stainless steel cavity and Samsung comes with ceramic enamel cavity. What is the difference between stainless steel vs ceramic enamel in terms of:

1. Durability
2. Ease of cleaning

Answer (score 4):

1. none
2. none

Both are durable and easy to clean, the factors I would look at instead are power, features, and user experience. Use a testing service like consumer reports in the US or Which? in the UK as a buying guide, they generally provide good information.

Answer (score -2):

i have both LG & SAMSUNG in my hotel , but i felt that stainless steel cavity would be good due to following reasons:-

1) better reflection of electromagnetic waves
2) faster heating
3) no leakage of electromagnetic waves ,that prevents the hazards on our body.
4) lower consumption of electricity than that of ceramic cavity , coz it needs more time to heat up.
5) I would prefer LG microwave due to its excellent customer service than Samsung.

Comment: You need to provide a source to substantiate your assertions here.